# Tier 2 UK visa + Chevening scholarship

Tags: visa, working-visas, uk-visa

I am currently applying for a tier 2 visa. At the same time, I have applied for Chevening scholarship and shortlisted to the interview phase. 
Will that reduce my visa application chance? In addition, does Entry Clearance Officer  go through my Chevening application details while assessing tier 2 visa?

Answer (score 1):

Under the UK visa policy, only one type of permission can be valid at a time, and overlapping time periods are not allowed. The Entry Clearance Officer at the issuing post will be aware of concurrent applications and may require clarification from you. That you applied for a scholarship within the same time frame that you applied for a general visa is not cause for refusal; it may be a simple matter of adjusting plans and the timing of the visa process.